# Google PlacePicker not showing the location suggestion

Tags: ios, google-places-api

Places SDK error: Error Domain=com.google.places.ErrorDomain Code=-3 "An internal error occurred in the Places SDK library. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/support)." UserInfo={NSLocalizedFailureReason=An internal error occurred in the Places SDK library. If you believe this error represents a bug, please file a report using the instructions on our community and support page (https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/support)., NSUnderlyingError=0x6000036d3090 {Error Domain=com.google.places.server.ErrorDomain Code=-1 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingError=0x6000036d2dc0 {Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={body=<48545450 2f312e31 20343034 204e6f74 20466f75 6e640d0a 436f6e74 656e742d 54797065 3a207465 78742f68 746d6c3b 20636861 72736574 3d555446 2d380d0a 44617465 3a204d6f 6e2c2031 34204f63 74203230 31392031 333a3430 3a303520 474d540d 0a457870 69726573 3a204d6f 6e2c2031 34204f63 74203230 31392031 333a3430 3a303520 474d540d 0a436163 68652d43 6f6e7472 6f6c3a20 70726976 6174652c 206d6178 2d616765 3d300d0a 436f6e74 656e742d 4c656e67 74683a20 390d0a0d 0a4e6f74 20466f75 6e64>, contentID=gtlr_23, GTLRStructuredError=GMSx_GTLRErrorObject 0x600003523d80: {code:3840 message:"The data couldn’t be read because it isn’t in the correct format."}, NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}}}}}

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TzAFS.png)

Comment: Can you explain when did the error happen?

Comment: Actually i am using GooglePalcePicker so when the place picker launch then it is showing this error.

Comment: I have attached the image as well

Comment: make sure there is a billing account associated with your project in Google Console

Comment: I am also facing this issue. Please let me know if anyone find any solution.

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the Place Picker has been deprecated as of January 29, 2019. This feature was turned off on July 29, 2019, and is no longer be available after that date. Please note that the old users that used Places SDK for iOS/Android are the only one who can still use the Place Picker during the deprecation period. The use of Places SDK for both platforms are now through enabling Places API and does not support the use of Place Picker anymore. You may see the deprecation notice in https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/placepicker.

> PlacePicker is no more.

Comment: I know but same configuration & key is working on Android.

Comment: It is totally deprecated for iOS if you find any solution for iOS apps let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following:

- [No Billing account linked to this project.](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project)
- [Use of an old Places SDK.](https://developers.google.com/places/ios-sdk/client-migration)
- [Reaching requests limits.](https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage)
- [Restricting App Key.](https://developers.google.com/maps/api-key-best-practices)

If all of this didn't fix your problem, I would recommend reaching out to [Google Support Team](https://console.cloud.google.com/google/maps-apis/support?project=utility-logic-158806&folder=&organizationId=) as this error commonly has something to do with your configuration in the [GCP console](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=utility-logic-158806) wherein only the support team of Google Maps Platform can assist you.